# EMI voltage ripple issue for low side NFET

Tags: emc, ripple, low-side

Under some user suggestion, I decided to drive my 10-ohm load heater using a low side NFET. I put a 1k resistor (R1) at the NFET gate to reduce ringing. I got, before placing the resistor,  a very bad Vpp of around 44V. Now the Vpp is around 26.7V. Is it ok for this kind of circuit? Or I need to add something more?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNjcm3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here is the oscilloscope output:

[image]

[image]

Do I need to add an input filter for my circuit? Is it needed? I would like to use a standard (certified) desktop power supply at 24V.

Comment: Your requirements need twisted pair to reduce load inductance and a spec for heat rise. Overshoot will reduce but is normal. The overshoot is not an issue unless you define it. ( do U have a spec?)  The risetime appears to be under the SOA curve for the result.

Comment: For a 40 V transistor, I would call it ok if this is your worst case scenario. You could perhaps get away with an RC snubber across your MOSFET if you need to damp further. What’s your max switch frequency you are planning on?

Comment: Have you an idea about the heater inductance ?

Comment: @winny switching frequency should be 60Hz or 30Hz. I need to test them both.

Comment: If you go with external RC, calculate your losses in R for 60 Hz and your max input voltage.

Comment: Do you have any decoupling capacitors on the 24 V rail by the way?

Answer (score 0):

To discharge the Cgs capacitance quicker you may add an RD network in parallel to R1.

R = 47 to 100 Ohm
D = 1N4148 or BAS16

The anode of D is connected to the gate of the MOSFET.

The cathode of D is connected to R.

This RD network is not an odd invention of mine but it's quite often used when driving the gate of an N MOSFET.